# How to list out all children of <ul>

Tags: jquery, html

my php will grab random row and write in to < ul > and < li > and it using html5 sortable

```
<ul id='sortable_A'>
<li>A1</li>
<li>A2</li>
<li>A3</li>
<li>A4</li>
</ul>
```

so now how can i using jquery to get all children of  in this way
var li_A = A1,A2,A3,A4
after i get it, then i will use it to update database accordingly

Ps: or have any other better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
           // Get all elements
var li_A = $('#sortable_A li')
           // Iterate on the elements and create an array 
            .map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
            })
            // Get the array
            .get()
            // join the values
            .join(',');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/hhkaV/

Answer (score 0):

```
var ul = $('ul').html();
```

And if you wanted you could use the `.each()` method to turn the list in to an array.

You should look at the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
 var listElements = $("ul#sortable_A li:not(:empty)");
```

List all  **li elements** that are not empty

Comment: what i get is [object Object]??

Comment: @user1493339 this might be a bug in jquery, I Have updated de answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
var li_A = [];
$('#sortable_A li').each(function(){
    li_A.push($(this).html());
});
```

Above code gives you an array of Strings. Also if you want a comma separated string then you can do this:

```
var str = li_A.toString();
```